# angularjs load data from mysql then dispaly by anglularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, json

this code is not working to display data from mysql using php and angularjs

html code -

```
<div class="container" ng-app="shoppingcart"
   ng-controller="shoppingcartcontroller">      <div class="row " >
            <div  class="box col-md-3" style="margin-top: 20px;"            ng-repeat="p in
   products">
                <div style="border: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: #f4f5f6">
                    <img src="/images/{{p.image}}.jpg" class="img img-responsive">
                    <h3>{{p.name}}</h3>
                    <h3>{{p.price}}</h3>
                </div>          </div>


        </div>  </div>
```

angular code -

```
<script >
            var app=angular.module("shoppingcart",[]);
            app.controller("shoppingcartcontroller",function($http,$scope){

                         $scope.loadproduct=function(){
                            $http.get("fetch.php").success(function(data){
                                    $scope.products=data;
                                });
                         };
                     });
        </script>
```

Comment: What does your fetch.php do? This would be the actual bottleneck.

Comment: Can you put the html code in a little detail.what is the result returned from fetch.php?Do you need to do ng-repeat?can you explain a little

Answer (score 0):

**A simple example**

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="p in products">
 {{p.name}}
 {{p.price}}
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app=angular.module("shoppingcart",[]); 

  app.controller("shoppingcartcontroller",function($http,$scope){

        $scope.loadproduct=function(){
                    $http.get("fetch.php").then(function(response){
                            $scope.products=response.data;
                        });
                 };
             });
```